# Compress and remove logs from jboss on linux with cron

Tags: linux, logging, cron, jboss, compression

I need to compress and remove log files after some time from serwer. I have never write scripts before.
So far i have script `logs.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGS=/usr/local/jboss/server/default/log/
INFOLOG="server.log"
ERRORLOG="error.log"
BOOTLOG="boot.log"

# gzip files last modify at least 7 days ago, and not files that are identified above and that have already been compressed
find $LOGS -mtime +7 -not -name "$INFOLOG" -not -name "$ERRORLOG" -not -name "$BOOTLOG" -not -name '*.gz' -exec gzip "{}" \;

# remove all logs older than 90 days
find $LOGS -mtime +90 -not -name "$INFOLOG" -not -name "$ERRORLOG" -not -name "$BOOTLOG" -print0 | xargs -0 -I xxx rm xxx
```

and i'm using cron to do it evry 5 minutes after 1 AM  from `jboss-logs.sh`

```
5 1 * * * /usr/local/jboss/server/default/logs.sh
```

and add cron with `crontab /root/jboss-logs.sh`

Is it correct? will it compress files older than 7 days and remove files older than 90? Will it works? It is safe - especially removing ?

Comment: I'd suggest you try it out by replacing the actual commands that touch files (i.e. gzip and rm) with something that prints out something like "Would gzip file xxxx.yy" and "Would rm file zzzz.ii". That way you'd see from the log cron outputs (or email if you configure it that way) what files it would touch at that moment and could validate if that is correct.

Comment: I've done exactly the same on Windows to archive logs. As long as the logs are saved a file per day basis (DailyRollingFileAppender) or more often (RollingFileAppender), the concept should work just fine (unless someone/something alters the mtime to be older, and that is likely not going to happen inadvertedly).However, why would you want to run the script every five minutes? It would be enough to run it once a day, or at max a couple of times a day unless you get massive amounts of logs per day.

Comment: logrotate ftw...

Answer (score 1):

Use `logrotate` to rotate logs.

In */etc/logrotate.d/* you will find some already installed rotate patterns.

You basically define a pattern for files to handle on a daily base.

Logrotate is being triggered by *cron.daily*.

Use `man logrotate` to learn more about the easy, line based syntax.

Comment: To expound, `logrotate` handles compression, rotation and retention - exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`newsyslog.conf` contains exactly what you need.

`newsyslog` periodically check files and rotate/compress/delete files. Also `newsyslog` can send signals to the processes that initiate reopening of logfiles.